# Why isn't my log4j.properties file getting used?

Tags: ant, log4j

I have a log4j.properties file in my current directory that specifies some things to log at DEBUG level, and everything else as INFO:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{mm:ss} (%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n

log4j.logger.com.xcski=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.nutch.protocol.http=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher=DEBUG
```

And I run the project from ant:

```
<target name="crawl" depends="compile">
  <java classname="com.xcski.nutch.crawler.Crawler"
        maxmemory="1000m" fork="true">
      <classpath refid="run.classpath"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

But for some reason, the only output I get is from LOG.info(), not LOG.debug.  I'm sure it's something trivial, but I've been beating my head against the wall for an hour now and I thought I'd try SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current directory is not by default included in classpath. Did you add it explicitly?

Comment: D'oh!  I should have known that.